# Is it necessary to use mysqli_real_escape_string with data from <input type=number> inputs?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, mysql-real-escape-string

Just as the title states.  Is it a standard procedure/practice to escape number inputs?

I know text fields should be escaped, but i'm wondering if I need to escape numbers.

Comment: No. you should always use prepared statements. Also - you should NEVER EVER trust user input

Comment: basic rule of thumb: if you're allowing "outside" data into your query strings, then you should be escaping. just because a field might be numeric-only doesn't mean it's any less dangerous than a text field. And that means you should be using prepared statements, so you don't even have to THINK about escaping - the prepare stuff takes care of all that for you.

Comment: Ok thanks guys!  I really need to teach myself prepared statements soon.  Everywhere I look it seems like that has become the new thing to do.  I'm pretty much self taught and it everything I learn seems to change in a year or so. lol

Comment: @MortHub That's because when you're using prepared statements you don't put the values directly in the query, instead you put variables, and bind the values to those variables. This is a high priority thing to learn if you still escaping the values and put them in the query

Comment: It will definitely be my next priority.  I appreciate the clarification.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Prepared Statement. But if you don't wish to do that, at least cast some data type, for example:

```
<?php
$myVar = (int)$_POST['user_age'];
$myVar = (float)$_POST['user_salary'];
```